# android:null pointer at splash screen

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am making an app in which i have to implement **alpha effect** in splash screen and when i load image it gives `null pointer exception`.The basic Problem while starting animation.If i remove start animation then my animation do not start at all.I am really stuck.Any help will be appreciated.My code is as follows:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {


private Thread mSplashThread;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    System.out.println("hello");
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this; 

    Animation a1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        LinearLayout Ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayoutheader);
        System.out.println("hello1");
        Ll.startAnimation(a1);
         System.out.println("hello2");


    // The thread to wait for splash screen events
    mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    // Wait given period of time or exit on touch

                   // a.reset();


                    wait(6000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
            }

            finish();

            // Run next activity
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            stop();                    
        }
    };

    mSplashThread.start();        
}

}
```

Exception is at `L1.startAnimation(a1);`

Comment: Could you post full exception stack trace?

Comment: Any progress? Are you still stuck with this? Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: ya i tired and it worked . The problem was that the view in which i was showing image was empty.

Comment: Ok, good. Could you please accept one of the answers if it helped you? Or post your own solution if you think none of the answers were close. This way readers know, which answer was the most essential. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the view in which i was showing image was empty.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    // Splash screen view
    System.out.println("hello");
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splashscreen12);
    Animation scaleAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.alpha);
    iv.startAnimation(scaleAnim);
    scaleAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Start new activity after some delay
        TimerTask newActivity = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreeen.this,CallingActivity.class));
                SplashScreeen.this.finish();

            }
        };
        Timer t = new Timer(false);
        t.schedule(newActivity, 2500);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // DO NOTHING

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // DO NOTHING
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you forgot to call `setContentView`. You have to do that before calling `findViewById` [edit: doesn't solve the problem here]

Comment: i have written my whole code , please  see and tell me where i am wrong

Comment: Have you tried to debug and check what Jarno Argillander suggested? There must be a wrong identifier there... I created a simple test project and it works as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

`Ll` is null or `a1` is null and startAnimation throws the exception. The full stack trace shows, which one threw it.

Also:

- You might have accidentally typed `R.id.mainLayoutheader` instead of `R.id.mainLayoutHeader`.
- Check the name `R.anim.alpha` is correct.

Comment: its R.id.mainLayoutheader only but i tried stack trace but didnot get anything

Comment: Could you post the contents of `R.anim.alpha` and debug to see if `a1` is assigned to `null` after calling `startAnimation`?

Comment: Also debug and check if `Ll` is assigned `null` after `findViewById`. These two would help us to narrow down the problem area.

Answer (score 0):

You can try timer thread...use this link
http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/scheduling-a-timer-task-to-run-repeatedly/